# How to call a variable within a function if it runs under a Class

Tags: python-3.x, function, global-variables

How to call a variable within a function:

What is the Right approach:

- Should define the variable before [class](/questions/tagged/class) or
- We can define it under the [class](/questions/tagged/class) or [function](/questions/tagged/function)

**Sample Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time

timeStamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")  # <-- Is this right Approach
class Scanner:

    INFO = 0
    DEBUG = 3
    timeStamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") # <-- ?

    def __init__(self, config_file, verbose=False):
        """ Constructor """

    def ask_passwords(self):
    def ldap_init(self):
    def hosts_module_scanner(self):
    def users_module_scanner(self):
    def ldap_reporting(self, user_list):
            self.write_report(failed_users, "users_ldap_report-{}.txt".format(timeStamp))


def option_parser(prog_version):
if __name__ == '__main__':
    scanner.ask_passwords()
    scanner.ldap_init()
    scanner.hosts_module_scanner()
    scanner.users_module_scanner()
```

Note: In the above example it doesn't work if i define under `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call variables within a class, using the syntax:
self.variable_name = # whatever you're assigning the variable.

As for where abouts in the class, your best bet is within the def *init*_() bit.

edit:
As a more verbose answer. you'll define the variables in the **init** method as shown below.  Using self.variable in a class, but outside the methods  (class functions) will throw a "self is not defined" error.

```
class Scanner:
    def __init__(self, config_file, verbose=False):
        """ Constructor """
        self.INFO = 0
        self.DEBUG = 3
        self.timeStamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        #declare rest of variables here
    #other class methods go here
```

Comment: Thanks @RichAspden, in this case may be we can use `global variable` defined? because in my example above if i define this under Class it does not work.

Comment: Hey @kulfi I've added an example to show where you put the variable declarations.  Doing self.variable where you have them in your original code will throw an error, but doing it like my example won't.  
As for global variable, it's better if you steer clear of it unless you have a specific reason to use global.  If you use global, anything outside that class (functions, decarations, etc) that use those variables can alter the value of those variables marked as global.  Since you're using them as part of a class, you only really want the class methods altering the class variables.

Comment: @kulfi You're welcome, glad I could help!